# Nanopower op amp stability

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, oscillation

Has anybody got experience of using nanopower op amps e.g. [TLV521](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv521.pdf)? This op amp has a very low GBW. In unity gain mode, can a small load capacitor on the output (e.g. few hundred pF) push this op amp into oscillation? This is not well explained in the datasheet.

Comment: Did you read section 8.1.1 on p.12?

Comment: There is nothing special about nanopower op amps. You will have to do some research on op amp stability in general to understand how things work. You have phase margin in the AC characteristics and even a graph in the datasheet - frequency response vs Cload, page 9

Answer (score 2):

> *This is not well explained in the datasheet.*

I think the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv521.pdf) does a pretty good job explaining what you might want to know: -

[image]

Comment: Ok what about the ISL28194 though?

Comment: @Edba this is a Q and A site and not a forum where a question is allowed to evolve. If the data sheet doesn't give you an answer then, my advice is don't use it  OR, do some testing to see what might be permissible.